# How to show api data in angular using restanular

Tags: angular, api, frontend, rest, restangular

I am new at angular I want to show live scores of sports but I don't know how to fetch API data in angular frontend I am getting all data from API and I want to fetch whole data and show on frontend using restangular or HTTP request can someone me by telling how should I start with this please.

```
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

export function RestangularConfigFactory(RestangularProvider, _persist) {
    if (environment.production) {
        RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://cricapi.com/api/matches?apikey=<API KEY>');
    }
```

Comment: 1) Share code, share what you tried to solve this problem. 2) Share what you think should happen 3) Share what actually happens, including errors. 4) Try using punctuation. The better you can state your case, the more likely you get a good answer.

Comment: I have tried above function but i don't know how i can call data in HTML i will glad if helped